# Who is the clipboard asker?

Tags: x11, clipboard

A program running on the same X session is free to ask X for whatever's in the clipboard. I want to know *which* one is asking. Can it be determined?

Comment: Although there are two previous similar questions and it's possible this is a duplicate and they should have been edited instead, this one certainly isn't unclear and I find the close votes as such confusing. It's also a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: The posts on the right  are disscussing how to get the contents in clipboard, how about the visitor(s).

Answer (score 0):

Note that X11 really doesn't have a system-wide clipboard (unless you run a special application like `xclipboard` for this role, which your desktop may or may not do), cut and paste works through [selections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection#Selections), which involves a communication between the X11 client asking for the selection contents and the X11 client holding the selection.

So the server will certainly know *which* client is asking for the selection contents.

There are also various ways to snoop on the X11 client/server interaction, so I'm fairly certain it's possible to find out if some client is doing this, and if so, which client.

But I can't give you a ready-made recipe; you'd have to sit down, read through the protocol specifications and roll your own snooper.